# Why did Mozilla...safari have to make CSS more inconvenient with "-moz" and "-webkit" tags?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Odd question maybe, but can't find an explanation anywhere. Just don't see why the extra -moz and -webkit tags were necessary for new CSS3 properties when they could of kept it simple like the rest of the standard CSS properties. Wouldn't it be more simple to just use "box-shadow" for all browsers instead of using -moz-box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow...  Can someone explain why it is like this? I must be missing something.

Comment: @close voter: this is neither subjective or argumentative. There are actual factual reasons including the W3C recommendations as to why its done, meaning there's an answer.

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437502/why-do-browser-vendors-make-their-own-css-properties

Answer (score 8):

[Vendor prefixes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords) are there for properties which are proprietary or experimental.

Most of the CSS 3 specifications are not yet Candidate Recommendations, they are still being developed and subject to change.

Many of the properties covered by specifications which are Candidate Recommendations or more advanced are still being polished by the browser vendors who don't consider their own implementations ready.

The prefixes are dropped when the properties are considered ready for mainstream use. You'll see a specific example of this when Firefox 4 is released, when it starts supporting the standard box-shadow declaration rather than requiring -moz-box-shadow.

Comment: Ah, okay makes sense. Thanks. Just one thing...how would Mozilla for example trigger Firefox 3 to recognize properties without the vendor prefixes when they become standard without requiring the user to update to the latest version?

Comment: They wouldn't. The user would have to upgrade to the latest version … with the newer CSS engine that implements the properties better … along with the essential security fixes that mean the user should be upgrading anyway.

Comment: @John: They wouldn't. If, for example, something was different between the -moz-box-shadow and regular box-shadow implementations, that would cause retroactive problems. So, to target Fx3, you would continue to use the vendor-prefixed version until that browser died out or you stopped supporting it. (I don't think the shadow property has differences; just an example.)

Answer (score 3):

The "vendor extensions" are part of the W3C recommendation and let developers use new properties that are not finalized yet and won't get flagged as errors by the validator (eventually). For example, webkit and gecko handle some new CSS3 properties differently because the spec was not finalized till after they were used in those browsers.